# My CSS edits don't take effect

Tags: css

I don't have any optimisation plugin installed and cache off, I clear cache after the CSS edits but nothing happens? the original code works great, but when I edit a color the browser brings back the old code...
this is the code in my template.css right now!

```
a {
  color:#0C42CE;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

and this is the browsers code right now

```
color: #7AE;
text-decoration: none;
```

Fixed it was a permission issue..facepalm

Comment: Could it be a server issue? What happens if you delete the file from your server and upload it again? Alternatively, try using this cache-busting method: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css?v=3" />`, updating the number after every major edit.

Comment: Do you have more code you can show?

Comment: Post a screen shot of the HTTP headers for that CSS file.

Comment: Can you try to clear cache of browser?  using Ctrl+F5

Comment: It might be something to do with permissions because right after I tried deleting the template.css file, the front end was displaying "Failed deleting template.css" Thought Im editing and deleting from the cpanel and there shouldn't be permissions right? I'm using meetgavick template. And yes I've did cleared cache before and tried with different browsers also. And today I edited other CSS files without any problems..

Answer (score 3):

Open the CSS file in your browser, type Ctrl+f5. If it doesn't show the CSS modified, than you have a saving problem.

Comment: oups, yes i meant ctrl sorry

Comment: hey it solved my problem but can you explain what Ctrl + F5 actually do?

Comment: Refresh the page without keeping the browser cache. A simple refresh (f5) does keep the cache

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens because of a cascading order, so somewhere else the style for that selector is being declared. It is in fact a "cascading" style sheet. This is solved by adding !important after your declaration to override any previous style declarations. Example:

```
a, a:link, a:hover {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Regarding file permissions, whether you are editing from Cpanel or an external editor/ftp your file permissions in most site should be 755 for directories and 644 for files, and you should have no problems editing files.

Comment: Thanks but even with the !important, the value resets to its original value after reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is actually saved, and the changes are not pending between your computer and server because you need to enter a password.

You can [try these changes to .htaccess](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess/#prevent-caching-with-htaccess) to make the browser request the page every time. It is recommend to turn that off for static css files once you have everything working though.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you set the a:visited and a:link so that the color of your link is not different because you've already clicked it.

```
a:visited, a:link{
    color:red;
    etc....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax:

```
 <a href="" class="x">...........</a>
```

css will be defined as :

```
a.x{
color:#0C42CE;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

and

```
a:hover.x{
color:#0C42CE;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

and add your css file in

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/css/file.css" /></head>
```